# Opposite of Array.reduce() in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In my example, I'm bringing data from a sheet using Google Sheet API and NodeJS.

The data is returning as mentioned in the first picture, so I've created a function **Transform( )** to transform the first row as the properties of my objects, the result is in the second picture.

**My question is how to opposite that function and bring back the data as it was arrayed inside a big array as the first picture.**

```
Transform = async (data, opt) => {
  const Objectproperties = (
    await gsapi.spreadsheets.values.get(opt)
  ).data.values[0].map((val) => val.replace(/\s/g, ""));
  const rows = data.filter((currentRow, index) => index != 0);
  const objects = rows.map((array) => {
    return array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
      return {
        ...accumulator,
        [Objectproperties[index]]: currentValue,
      };
    }, {});
  });

  app.use(
    "/items",
    router.get("/", function (req, res) {
      res.send(objects);
    })
  );
```

[Picture1: mapping the data coming from the sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8SNy.png)
[Picture2: using the first row as the properties of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8SNy.png)

Comment: Both images are the same.

Comment: Put input data and expected destination format example here as a json.

Comment: The images have personal details that are poorly hidden.  Completely erase them.  Even better create a sample data set with fake names, emails and facebook urls.

Comment: with reduce, there generally isn't a 100% way of unpacking what was previously packed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, your reduce function is simply converting an array into a indexed dictionary. Thus to reverse it, you just need to extract the dictionary values:

```
rows = objects.map((dict) => Object.values(dict))
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked just fine, much obliged

Comment: You might also want to have a look at the lodash library. Its a general purpose toolbox for functional programing and data manipulation. Your reduce is essentually doing the _.keyBy() function - https://lodash.com/docs/#keyBy